# Io socket reset connection upon disconnect or reload

Tags: javascript, sockets, io

I'm using io sockets for my sites live chat function. When I start the server and then load the client page for the first time, it works like it's supposed too.

However, if I leave the page and then load it again while having the server running, my problem occurs. The server logs that I both disconnect and then reconnected. But the intended functions of the connection does not work. When I try to add a new message to the chat, it will not show up.

Here is my server code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

console.log("user connected");

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("user disconnected");
    socket.disconnect();
})
})
```

And my client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('IP');

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
socket.reconnect();
});
```

Is there some way to completely reset the connection between the client and the server upon disconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently, it was resolved by forcing a new connection described:
http://socket.io/docs/client-api/

```
this.io = socket(this.host, forceNew : true})
```

Comment: `http://socket.io/docs/client-api/` not accessible anymore. [Client options: forcenew | Socket.IO](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#forcenew)